# React router private route not redirecting

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I've got a private route which redirects to an Auth component if there is nothing in local storage. At the moment it's not taking the storage into account as it takes me to the Auth page when there is local storage data and when there isn't. I am using redux in the application but not for this part yet, I wanted to get it working with a basic set up first.

I think may be my component hasn't had time to reload and register that there's a storage item. I can see it trying to navigate away but comes straight back to Auth. Can anyone help?

My private route:

```
export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false);


    useEffect(() => {

        const userData: any = localStorage.getItem('userData');

        if (!userData) {
            setIsAuthenticated(false);
        }

        setIsAuthenticated(true);



    }, [dispatch])


    return (

        <Route {...rest} render={(props: any) => 
            isAuthenticated ?
                <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to="/auth" />
        } />
    );
};
```

Component containing my routes:

```
export const Main = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <MainContainer className="MainContainer">
                <Switch location={location || background}>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Home />
                    </Route>
                    <ProtectedRoute /*isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}*/ component={Nativers} path="/nativers" exact />
                </Switch>
            </MainContainer>

        </>
     )
 }
```

The auth component function handling any redirecting when you click on the login/sign up button:

```
    const authHandler = async () => {

        let action;
        if (isSignUp) {

            action = AuthActions.signup(
                formState.inputValues.name,
                formState.inputValues.email,
                formState.inputValues.password,
                formState.inputValues.repeatPassword
            )
        } else {
            action = AuthActions.login(
                formState.inputValues.email,
                formState.inputValues.password
            )
        }
        setError(null);
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            await dispatch(action);
            return <Redirect to="/nativers" />;
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message);
            setIsLoading(false); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what prompts the `ProtectedRoute` to rerender once `isAuthenticated` has been set to true or false after the component mounts? (*dispatch likely won't update again to rerun effect*) It's mounted and sitting there in your `Router` and unless a prop changes (also likely won't with `Route` components), it won't ever rerender unless `Main` does.

Comment: I thought this might be the issue but not sure how I can force it to re-render? I suppose instead of relying on the component's isAuthenticated, I could dispatch to my redux store to make sure its recorded in there that they're authenticated. Then in my Main component, fetch that state and pass it to ProtectedRoute to make sure it checks on that. It should update thus making Main re-render?

Answer (score 2):

When the page path is updated, the matching `Route` component(s) is called to render whatever component was registered with it. The right place to put the logic to either redirect or not depending on the availability of `localStorage` data should be inside the `Route` component because that’s where it is guaranteed to be executed before render of the registered component.

However, in your code, this logic is placed outside the `Route` component and even though you are trying to use `dispatch` to update the value of `isAuthenticated` variable, the update would only happen if the `ProtectedRoute` component is re-rendered because of the way the `useEffect` hook is setup.

There are multiple ways to fix this, but given what you already have, I think the easiest would be to do some thing like this:

```
export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  return (
      <Route {...rest} render={(props: any) => 
        localStorage.getItem('userData') ?
              <Component {...props} />
              : <Redirect to="/auth" />
      } />
  );
};
```

Now, the logic to redirect or not lives inside the `Route` component, consequently, whenever, there is page path matches that of the `Route` component, the logic is executed and a redirect happens if needed.

Comment: This worked nicely thank you! I'd like to scale this going forward and also check that in that storage item there is a valid token etc. Would you recommend I not do this inside a hook then and instead extract into a separate function which would replace the getItem?

Comment: Yes. You can have a function somewhere that does all the check needed to decide what to render and then call the function in the render props.